# My windows batch script for copying files doesn't work, why?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, batch-file, cmd, backup

I just want a simple script to backup some files with task scheduler, but copying just wouldn't work in a batch file.

I want something like this:

```
chcp 65001
set destination=e:\backup\utorrent\%date%backup\
mkdir "%destination%"
copy "d:\Programok\utorrent\aktuális\*.dat" "%destination%"
```

But even this doesn't work in a batch, but works when I enter the commands manually in a cmd window.

```
chcp 65001
set destination=e:\backup\utorrent\%date%backup
mkdir "%destination%"
copy "d:\Programok\utorrent\aktuális\settings.dat" "%destination%\settings.dat"
```

Comment: Which error do you see when running batch ?

Comment: Why do you change the codepage?

Comment: The batch and manual examples you give aren't exactly the same. What happens if you try `copy "d:\Programok\utorrent\aktuális\*.dat" "%destination%"` by hand? Any error message there?

Comment: @mfm4aa 
It didn't handle the path names properly

Comment: @Mr Fuzzy Button 
No. But with that the CMD window closed even if I was adding the commands manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Unicode, use [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding:

```
chcp 1252
set destination=e:\backup\utorrent\%date%backup\
mkdir "%destination%"
copy "d:\Programok\utorrent\aktuális\*.dat" "%destination%"
```